# How to make a global "addEventListener" function that is re-usable to both clicks and keyboard events - Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, button, addeventlistener, code-reuse

I want to have a single re-usable function for two events.

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const listItems = document.getElementById("list-items");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");

inputEl.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
     if (event.key === "Enter"){
     listItems.innerHTML = inputEl.value
     }
});
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
     listItems.innerHTML = inputEl.value
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-el">

<button id="add-btn">Add to List</button>

<ul id="list-items"></ul>
```

The function should allow me to parse in either "Enter" key event after user presses on enter key or a "click" after user clicks on button.
currently, I have two the functions for each event.

The two functions are working okay but I was wondering if there was a way to make a function that is more re-usable when listening to events.

Comment: So basically`event => { if( event.type === 'click' || event.key === 'Enter' ){ /* DO YOUR THING*/ } }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for either of the conditions to be true, as both function receive an `event` with more info about it, so you can just ask whether it's a click event or whether the key in the event matches the key you are looking for:

```
event.type === 'click' || event.key === 'Enter'
```

Like this:

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const listItems = document.getElementById("list-items");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");

function addItem( event ){
    
  if( event.type === 'click' || event.key === 'Enter' ){
     
    event.preventDefault();

    listItems.appendChild( document.createElement( 'li' ) ).textContent = inputEl.value;
    
  }
  
}

inputEl.addEventListener( "keypress", addItem );
addBtn.addEventListener( "click", addItem )
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-el">

<button id="add-btn">Add to List</button>

<ul id="list-items"></ul>
```